# Favorite a user on stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes I like the profile of a certain user. It would be great if one could bookmark it or favorite it. People mention little bits of info that may be useful to me such as - their blog, certifications taken, their public resume etc.

Comment: Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange are not social networks. You are always free to bookmark a users profile page.

Comment: Try pressing ctrl-D. Ta dah!

Comment: @Juhana - i mentioned that already. But i don't want my browser to be full of bookmarks. Okay, I can make a separate folder for SO. But how will ctrl + D directly bookmark to that folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll all the way to the bottom right of a user profile and you'll find an RSS icon.

Comment: No, I did not mean that. I meant that we could keep a link to his profile within our profile. Of course, I can bookmark it in my browser, but having it inside SO would be nicer.

Comment: @davidblaine You can add it to your "About me" section, if you *really* want to.

Comment: @RobW - no, I mean - If you like a user's profile, then you should be able to bookmark it so that you can visit it later. I don't need the RSS feeds and such. Besides, my about me has an interesting description. Do check it out.

Comment: @davidblaine: We know what you ment, and that is a duplicate. We are giving you work-arounds.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I agree that my question is a duplicate and deserves to be closed. But at least the guys should let it remain at 0 points instead of negative. They look at my profile, laugh and then down vote. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @davidblaine: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. People are voting on your feature request.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - okay i understand now. thanks